# How can I identify this RAF pin badge?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

I am trying to identify the man in the photo below, and I am hoping that his uniform in this picture gives some clues. I am told he was in the RAF, though I know nothing of his role. The pin badge/brooch and overall style of the uniform look potentially identifiable.

I believe the most likely date range for the photo is 1930s-1940s.

[image: Man in uniform]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the [Observer Single Wing](https://www.brittonsbadges.co.uk/en-GB/all-badges-currently-in-stock/a-wwii-padded-raf-observers-brevet/prod_10247) badge above his breast pocket, which was withdrawn in 1942 and replaced by the [Navigator Single Wing](https://www.epicmilitaria.com/raf-navigators-wing.html) [badge](https://www.epicmilitaria.com/british-ww2/british-insignia/raf-wings-badges.html).

[image]

Comment: Excellent find. In addition, his rank is Flight Lieutenant. You can tell by the number of stripes on his cuff. See here for more details: https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/RAF_officer_ranks